# Is there a more efficient algorithm for determining the existence of k internally vertex-disjoint paths?

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, max-flow

I’m trying to find an algorithm that given two non-adjacent vertices *s* and *t*, and a *k* > 0, it determines only the existence of *k* internally vertex-disjoint paths (the vertex-disjoint paths themselves do not need to meet any specific requirements, we only care about existence).

I’ve found a couple possible candidates, namely [Suurballe’s algorithm](http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/Disjoint_Path_Finding) and [this academic paper](https://iajit.org/PDF/vol.12,no.6/7418.pdf) describing another algorithm that is similar.

The only thing I’ve found that directly addresses my question is [this academic paper](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Emchudnov/tournpaths.pdf), which proves that there exists a polynomial time algorithm for determining that there are at least *k* vertex-disjoint paths for all *k*.

I’ll be using this algorithm to determine that the the *k*-vertex-connectivity of a graph is at least *k*, as described in [this paper](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/handle/1813/6027/73-184.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).

For the algorithm, the graph can be treated as undirected since for every edge going from vertices *s* to *t*, there also exists an edge going from *t* to *s*.

Can you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be related to C though.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb, I tagged C since I’m implementing the algorithm in C, my bad for the confusion haha.

Comment: Directed or undirected graph?

Comment: Are there any constraints on the host graphs?

Comment: @John Bollinger: It is an undirected graph represented as a directed graph (i.e., every edge going from vertex A to vertex B also has an edge going in the reverse direction from vertex B to vertex A).

Comment: @John Bollinger: The host graph is a simple graph (no self-loops nor parallel edges).